# sharding counters in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

HI guys I am new to google app engine, can u guys explain the below code, especially why counter Param is used and what declare parameters. I have no source and helpless. I am eager to learn about this concept, Help me guys...

```
import PMF;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.jdo.Query;

public class ShardedCounter {
  private String counterName;

  public ShardedCounter(String counterName) {
    this.counterName = counterName;
  }

  public String getCounterName() {
    return counterName;
  }


  public int getCount() {
    int sum = 0;
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

    try {
      Query shardsQuery =
          pm.newQuery(GeneralCounterShard.class, "counterName == nameParam");
      shardsQuery.declareParameters("String nameParam");

      List<GeneralCounterShard> shards =
          (List<GeneralCounterShard>) shardsQuery.execute(counterName);
      if (shards != null && !shards.isEmpty()) {
        for (GeneralCounterShard current : shards) {
          sum += current.getCount();
        }
      }
    } finally {
      pm.close();
    }

    return sum;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got this code but they have a [great article here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters).

The idea behind sharded counters is to have a counter that has a high "hit rate". Lets say you need a website that has 100k's of users all clicking an "Awesome" button on pictures. With Google App Engine (GAE) you have a storage system called the [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) which is great for storing that kind of information. The draw back is it can only be updated by one person at a time. So if 5 people like the same photo at the exact same moment you will get something called "[contention](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention)".

To avoid contention you have a shard counter. Instead of one counter that needs to be updated you have many that then pool their numbers to get the grand total. (Another analogy), you need to count the number of vehicles on a multi-lane high way, instead of one person trying to count them all you have many each counting a lane then add their numbers together at the end.

In practice (taken from the first link) you have a Kind lets called "ShardedCounter". It has many shards (or people counting). When you need to increment the counter you call the method 'increment' that randomly chose one of its shards to increment then does the addition for you. Basically splitting all the request to increment the counter "evenly" between all of its shards. Thereby reducing the chance of contention. When you need the actual count it loops through all the counters, adding them up and returns the actual count.

I hope that makes sence, otherwise drop me a comment and I'll do my best to answer.

I'd like to note I haven't done shard counters in Java but have many times in Python

Comment: The link you have given is the one I was referring. If u help me out with java code, it would be helpful for me